# email confirmation verification

Tags: c#, wcf, xamarin.forms

I have a Wcf service and an Xamarin.forms mobile application, when the user registers from the mobile app I want the web service to send an email verification to the user, when the user goes to his/her email and clicks the link the user account will be activated.

I only have one solution which is to have the user id in the verification link and give the service url followed by verification function and user id.

Is there a better secure way to do so as I dont want to give wcf link in the link?

```
private void SendEmailConfirmation(String EmailId,string UserId)
        {
            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            string emailId = EmailId;
            msg.From = new MailAddress("YourGmailEmailId@gmail.com");           
            msg.To.Add(emailId);
            msg.Subject = "Confirmation email for account activation";
            //For testing replace the local host path with your lost host path and while making online replace with your website domain name
            //string ActivationUrl = "http://localhost:8665/FetchUserId(emailId) & "&EmailId=" & emailId);
            msg.Body ="Thanks for showing interest and registring in <a href='http://www.activationlink.com'> webservice.com<a> " +
                  " Please Thanks!";
            msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("emailaddress@gmail.com", "mypassword");
            smtp.Port = 587;
            smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
            smtp.EnableSsl = true;
            //NetworkCredential Credentials = new NetworkCredential("emailaddress@gmail.com", "Super2@17");
            //smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            smtp.Send(msg);
        }
```

Comment: What is your question? Is it the identification of the user? The confirmation link?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function to generate a non sensible code (like a token, hash, guid or something like this) and associate this to the user data and a date limit to activate that link (24 hours for example).

Then, when the user click this link with the token, you verify if the token is still valid and enable the user's account.

Answer (score -2):

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
```

You will need to import the above namespaces.

Comment: Sending the mail is not the issue of the OP.